# Conversion of X and Y coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system

I have been researching some Tennessee Valley Authority (TVA) documents from 1947 that show the location of an item of interest to me as X=3,160,900 and Y=730,000. But, when I try to get Google Maps to display this location, it doesn't like my coordinates. Perhaps TVA's X and Y coordinates were created using an antiquated values system. Can you explain how I can convert TVA's coordinates to modern GPS values that Google Maps will accept?

Comment: What general area is the feature located in? That might help us figure out if the TVA system is using some sort of local coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

Those coordinates appear to be in NAD27/Tennessee EPSG:2204.  The location plots to the center of Watauga Lake which is a TVA project.  Or maybe this deprecated CRS, EPSG 32036? https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32036/html/

There are conversion tools online or you could use something like Python, and pyproj.   https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NCAT/
[image]

[image]

Comment: EPSG:2274 is also in TN, but west and south of this point - I think its the same as EPSG:2204 but with "survey feet" units rather than "US feet".  Careful not to trip over your feet. Found via projfinder.com

Comment: Yep,  but the poster stated that the coordinates came from a 1947 publication so I figured it was not in a 1983 datum. https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83-tennessee-ftus/